# Non-namespace folder naming convention

Tags: visual-studio-2010, namespaces, naming-conventions, directory-structure, partial-classes

I'm working on a project in C# .NET (*Visual Studio 2010*) with a number of generated partial classes, metadata classes, etc. (*if you know Entity Framework, you know what I mean*)

My question pertains to the practice of correlating namespaces with directories, whereby each directory denotes a sub-namespace.

Now, I'd like to move the metadata classes into a sub-directory, purely for organizational purposes. Since partial classes must exist within the same namespace, the `Metadata` sub-directory can no longer denote a namespace (*otherwise it'd break the partial classes*) I'd be departing from the aforementioned practice; not a big deal, but I like sticking to a standard.

Is there a convention to denote that a given directory is purely organizational?

Off-hand, prefixing the directory name with "`.`" (*dot*) or "`_`" (*underscore*) seems appropriate, the former more than the latter since it would result in an invalid namespace name.

---

@Pheonixblade9, something like this:

```
:
|
+- ProjectFolder/
|   +- App.config
|   +- Packages.config
|   +- ClassA.cs
|   +- ClassB.cs
|   +- ClassC.cs
|   +- ClassD.cs
|   +- Metadata/
|   |   +- ClassA.Metadata.cs  \
|   |   +- ClassB.Metadata.cs   \ These are the partial classes that shouldn't
|   |   +- ClassC.Metadata.cs   / be namespaced differently than their respective
|   |   +- ClassD.Metadata.cs  /  partials in the parent folder
:   :
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the directory structure?  via picture or text would be fine

Comment: Thanks!  That should make the question easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite @JohanLarsson providing the correct answer for 2012+, I've opted for the `.` prefix on the directory:

```
:
+- ClassC.cs
+- ClassD.cs
+- .Metadata/
|   +- ClassA.Metadata.cs
|   +- ClassB.Metadata.cs
:   :
```

This renders the namespace name provided to classes created in that folder invalid. It's more of an implicit indicator than an explicit rule as I'd have preferred (*and as @JohanLarsson's answer provides*) but then again, I'm the sucker running 2010.

I'm still open to answers, and will gladly change acceptance to something better.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the folder in solution explorer
2. In properties set NameSpace Provider to false

Comment: I'm guessing step `0.` is upgrade from VS 2010?

Comment: Good suggestion, and definitely something to consider for those running 2012. When/if I manage to get onto 2012, I'll certainly use this feature, but for the time being I'm stuck on 2010 :-(

Comment: I remember seeing this option, but looks like it was taken away or moved in VS2022 :(